# How to set caret position before/After div

Tags: javascript, tinymce, textarea

I am the author of a plugin on TinyMCE that allows to add a collapse block in the editor. When a user clicks on the plugin button here is what is inserted :

```
<div class="card csscard0">
    <div class="card-header cssHeader0">
        <a class="card-link collapsed" style="color: black;" href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">
            TITLE
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse not-show">
         <div class="card-body">
              CONTENT
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here is a picture of the result, and as you can see on the picture, I can set my caret just before the created div. (red arrow)

[image]

Okay, so now that I've laid out the facts, here's my problem.

I can add blocks like the one right above inside other blocks like this:
[image]

As you can see with the red arrow, I can't set my caret before the div anymore, It automatically puts him inside the block.

```
<div class="card csscard0">
   <div class="card-header cssHeader0">
        <a class="card-link collapsed" style="color: black;" href="#collapse18" data-toggle="collapse">Titre
        </a>
   </div>
   <div id="collapse18" class="collapse show">
      <div class="card-body">
         <br />
         <div class="card csscard1">
            <div class="card-header cssHeader1"><a class="card-link collapsed" style="color: black;" href="#collapse19" data-toggle="collapse">Titre</a></div>
            <div id="collapse19" class="collapse show">
               <div class="card-body">Contenu</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to know what "trick" can I add to be able to set my cursor before or even after the whole block.

Here is a fun fact :

I'm in a company so i'm forced to use my website on old IE9 or Mozila firefox. But when I try my plugins on Chrome I can actually set my caret just before the block. Any idea why?

[image]

## EDIT

This is the code that initializes tinymce :

```
<script>      
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea#contenuEtask',
                relative_urls: false,
                language: 'fr_FR',
                contextmenu: false,
                browser_spellcheck: true,
                end_container_on_empty_block: true,
                plugins: "noneditable code wordcount autolink anchor fullscreen lists advlist link image hr tabfocus table spoiler picto powerpaste",
                toolbar1: 'fullscreen code | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline| link image table | bullist numlist outdent indent ',
                toolbar2: 'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor | spoiler-add spoiler-hide spoiler-close | warning-add new-add note-add |hr',
                noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
                noneditable_editable_class: "mceEditable",
                powerpaste_html_import: 'merge',
                powerpaste_word_import: 'clean',
                menubar: "",
                height: 500,
                convert_urls: false,
               
                setup: function (editor) {
                    editor.on('init', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val();
                        this.setContent(tinyHtml);
                    });
                    editor.on('keyup', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = this.getContent();
                        $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val(tinyHtml);
                    });
                    editor.on('click', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = this.getContent();
                        $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val(tinyHtml);
                    });
                    editor.on('mouseover', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = this.getContent();
                        $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val(tinyHtml);
                    });
                    editor.on('mouseout', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = this.getContent();
                        $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val(tinyHtml);
                    });  
                }
            });
            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'contenuEtask');
        </script>
```

### What I already try

I read a lot of forum before asking my question but no proposed solution has corrected my problem. I already try

```
auto_focus:true,
```

option of TinyMCE. I try to add span, div.. But nothing changes.

Comment: I don't know but I think autofocus is your candidate that'll help you. https://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus

Comment: So... how should I interpret this? I could never get my users to select around the div while there is no update of explorer ? @Mohit

Comment: Inside your div's, you must be having some <input/> where you want the cursor right?

Comment: No i have nothing more than what I share you through this code. I edit my post to add my tinymce declaration. ;)